# Отрисовка сетки для заднего фона

Tags: javascript, canvas

Имеются такой код:

```
function drawGrid() 
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#ccc";
    for(var x = rectPosX; x <= rectPosX + rectWidth; x += gridSize) 
    {
        context.moveTo(x, rectPosY);
        context.lineTo(x, rectPosY + rectHeight);
    }
    for(var y = rectPosY; y <= rectPosY + rectHeight; y += gridSize) 
    {
        context.moveTo(rectPosX, y);
        context.lineTo(rectPosX + rectWidth, y);
    }
    context.stroke();
}
```

эта функция выполняется всегда, когда выполняется событие прокрутки мыши, и при этом изменяется переменная, отвечающая за размер квадратов в сетке *gridSize*.
Проблема в том, когда размер клеток становится очень маленьким, скрипт начинает подвисать из - за большого количества линий. Есть варианты как это дело оптимизировать, что бы не подвисало? Хотелось бы достичь эффекта примерно как в Visio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь изображено 9 листов А4 формата и при увеличении изображения лагов нету

Comment: адаптивная сетка Вам нужна? воспроизводимый пример есть?

Comment: хотел привести в пример визио онлайн, но к моему удивлению не нашел его.
https://www.draw.io/ там в принципе хороший пример, он без лагов увеличивает и уменьшает сетку. Сейчас прикреплю фотографию этой сетки

Comment: лучше конечно изображение(гиф) чтобы вопрос был самодостаточен

Comment: щас попробую гиф добавить

Comment: Вас утроит адаптивная сетка?

Comment: если подгрузок 3-5 секудных не будет, то да. На Draw io тоже адаптивная, но когда много клеток на экране генерируется, там не лагает, а мой код лагает(

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/LqPAsh5ryw8ahgyM9E вот гиф, на сайт не влезла. У меня экран широкоформатный, так на весь экран квадратики практически сразу генерируются там

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103206/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-helldrg).